# Swing layout which does not increase spacing when resized

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

Which swing layout ensures that increasing the size of the container will be compensated by increasing its padding on the side (right in my case) and will keep spacing between components constant?

Comment: `GridBagLayout`...with a little trickery...

Comment: BoxLayout, or `null` layout, which will enable you to position the components with absolute position, however, this is tricky and hard to maintain.

Comment: 'BoxLayout' does not increase spacing. But both left & right padding is increased. How do I achieve that it is alligned left? Morever there is some sort of top padding. How do I achieve components placed at y=0?

Comment: Use a "left aligned" `FlowLayout`. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem is you need more help.